# Photoshop Image Resize Query

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have a flyer in MS Word format which I need to finalize in JPEG format image with the 1920 pixel width × 700 pixel height. I have converted the file contents from MS Word to an image PNG file.

However, I could not set the image size as mentioned above in Photoshop. If I set the image width to 1920 pixels, then the height is automatically adjusted to some other value, and vice-versa.

Please guide me on how to perform image resize in Photoshop. I am new to Photoshop, detailed guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That's because you have locked the aspect ratio (the chain symbol). But if you don't lock the aspect ratio the image will be stretched ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to avoid the stretching and get the desired size?

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to help you since you seem to misunderstand several things. 1. Don't use Word to design a flyer. 2. For sharp text and vector shapes on print, don't use JPG but PDF (Word can export PDF). 3. For print, don't think in pixels, but physical dimensions. 4. The format you want is landscape, but your design seems to be portrait. Can't you just send 700 x 1920 px or rotate your image? 5. The given pixel dimensions seem too small for print in good quality (ideally about 16 x 6 cm). 6. Image aspect ratio can't be changed without stretching graphics - you'll need to redesign.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Do not use Word to "design" a flyer. 2. Do not use Word to "design" a flyer.

Answer (score 2):

Buddy, 1920 Width and 700 Height is gonna make your image Landscape.
I'm Guessing you want 1920 HEIGHT and 700 WIDTH.

To do that,

**1.** Press ***CTRL+ALT+I*** .

**2.** Click on the chain-block icon.

[image]

**3.** Enter the desired values.

[image]

Now, to avoid stretching, you can try cropping the image.